# How to get the difference between current time and a given timeStamp

Tags: android, date, unix-timestamp

I am given a unix timeStamp and I need to calculate the difference between current time and the given unix timestamp like:

```
2 sec ago
5 mins ago
2 hours ago
3 days ago
```

So I have written below code:

```
String time = "given unix timeStamp";
Date date = new Date();
date.setTime(Long.parseLong(time) * 1000);
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.setTime(date); // given time
Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.setTime(new Date()); // current time

Integer[] elapsed = new Integer[6];
Calendar clone = (Calendar) start.clone(); 
elapsed[0] = elapsed(clone, end, Calendar.YEAR);
clone.add(Calendar.YEAR, elapsed[0]);
elapsed[1] = elapsed(clone, end, Calendar.MONTH);
clone.add(Calendar.MONTH, elapsed[1]);
elapsed[2] = elapsed(clone, end, Calendar.DATE);
clone.add(Calendar.DATE, elapsed[2]);
elapsed[3] = (int) (end.getTimeInMillis() - clone.getTimeInMillis()) / 3600000;
clone.add(Calendar.HOUR, elapsed[3]);
elapsed[4] = (int) (end.getTimeInMillis() - clone.getTimeInMillis()) / 60000;
clone.add(Calendar.MINUTE, elapsed[4]);
elapsed[5] = (int) (end.getTimeInMillis() - clone.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000;

submissionTime.setText(elapsed[0] + " years," + elapsed[1] + " months,"
    + elapsed[2] + " days," + elapsed[3] + " hours," + elapsed[4]
    + " minutes," + elapsed[5] + " seconds");
```

And this is the `elapsed()` function:

```
public static int elapsed(Calendar before, Calendar after, int field) {
    Calendar clone = (Calendar) before.clone();
    int elapsed = -1;
    while (!clone.after(after)) {
        clone.add(field, 1);
        elapsed++;
    }
    return elapsed;
}
```

But this is giving me wrong input. I am new in Java/Android date manipulation and some full working code will be helpful.

Comment: `giving me wrong input` do you mean wrong output?  If so, please provide real examples of input and output.

Comment: Works for me. What exactly is "wrong"?